# When do I need a custom readObject/writeObject in a Serialised object?

Tags: android, exception, serialization

I am trying to save an object via Serialisation. I get a NotSerializableException.
I notice that I only get it when I have instantiated another object within the object I am trying to save.
Am I mean to write my own versions of readObject/writeObject for this?

Answer (score 0):

Any object within a serialised object also has to be serialised, if you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

theblitz, the new object you put inside your object must implement Serializable too.